# Power Query - Counting non blanks in column in Group function

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm not a pro in writing code from scratch in Power Query, rather clicking it and tweaking only to my needs and I got stuck when using Group function. There is only option of counting rows and I would like to count non blank cells in specific column.

Code looks like this:

```
= Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", 
     {"Company Name", "Policy Number", "Division", "Date"}, 
         {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, 
         {"Sum", each List.Sum([Claim Amount]), type number
         }
     })
```

it has to group data by four fields (Company Name, Policy Number, Division, Date) and return number of claims and sum of claims.

I tried changing it to use Counta function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/counta-function-dax example below:

```
= Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", 
     {"Company Name", "Policy Number", "Division", "Date"}, 
         {{"Count", each List.Counta([Claim Amount]), type number}, 
         {"Sum", each List.Sum([Claim Amount]), type number
         }
     })
```

and many other variations of above but without any luck. Can you help me and tell what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT: I already considered removing nulls before grouping but I actually need information that in certain group there were 0 claims in particular month.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your "blank" fields are in fact null (which it sounds like they are based on what you said), you can use List.NonNullCount to get to count of items in the field that are, well, not null.

```
= Table.Group(#"Replaced Value", 
     {"Company Name", "Policy Number", "Division", "Date"}, 
         {{"Count", each List.NonNullCount([Claim Amount]), type number}             
     })
```

Comment: Perfect, it woked without a fail! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=List.NonNullCount(Record.FieldValues(_))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just filter the blanks then do group?

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Claim Amount] <> null)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Company Name", "Policy Number", "Division", "Date"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"Sum", each List.Sum([Claim Amount]), type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is good idea which I already considered unfortunately for further use i need also information in which month there were no claims. When I filter out blanks this disappears and creates more problems in next parts of analysis. I am so desperate I even considered having two separate queries one to do these counts other to calculate the sum and then merging them but it sounds like there should be a nicer solution to do that...